# Github не отображает активность, хотя всё настроено верно

Tags: git, github

подскажите пожалуйста, почему гит хаб не отображает активность в профиле, в самом репозитории активность показывается. Почта и имя прописаны верно, не знаю на что думать, начал даже делать commit в основную ветку, всё равно не помогает. Коммиты делаю каждый день, в активности показывается лишь очень старые записи когда я только создал пару репозиториев

Comment: Так ты их на гитхаб-то пушишь?

Comment: да пушу их с помощью:  git push -u origin main

Comment: Честно говоря, изображения в вопросе не дают никакой информации, которая позволила бы сказать что-то определенное. Можно их убрать и вопрос ничего не потеряет. Я к тому, что скртншоты должны что-то добавлять, например, скрин ваших коммитов, где виден автор и скрин коммитов на гитхаб, где виден ИХ автор.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, убрал. просто мой первый вопрос

Comment: Я написал не совсем для этого. Я к тому, что доказательств, что "все верно" в вопросе нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась до банального проста, у меня в файле `.gitconfig`, почта `user.email` была указана в кавычках. В файле убрал кавычки, всё заработало.
Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю Вам нужно почитать официальную документацию (или ответ на этот вопрос) от **GitHub**, который отвечает на этот вопрос.

Коммиты появятся на графике ваших вкладов, если они соответствуют всем следующим условиям:

- Адрес электронной почты, используемый для коммитов, связан с вашей
  учетной записью на GitHub.com.
- Коммиты были сделаны в автономном репозитории, а не в форке.
- Были сделаны коммиты:В ветке репозитория по умолчанию или в ветке gh-pages (для репозиториев с сайтами проектов) *Дополнительную информацию о сайтах проектов см. в разделе* [«О страницах GitHub»](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#types-of-github-pages-sites).

Кроме того, должно выполняться хотя бы одно из следующих условий:

- Вы являетесь соавтором репозитория или членом организации, которой
  принадлежит репозиторий.
- Вы разветвили репозиторий
- Вы открыли запрос на включение или проблему в репозитории.
- Вы пометили репозиторий звездочкой.

https://docs.github.com/ru/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/managing-contribution-settings-on-your-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile

Comment: Да это читал всё соответствует

Comment: Если не показывается, значит, что-то не соответствует.

Comment: @YashProgrammost Тщательно перепроверьте все пункты и убедитесь в соответствии. Если ничего не получится свяжитесь в поддержкой GitHub. https://support.github.com/request?tags=dotcom-footer